# Why does .write not add the ints into the file? Java

Tags: java, io

I had a question regarding the File.io library. So in a class I had an assignment [The Class Assignment](https://blackboard.wccnet.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-4169341-dt-content-rid-19080877_1/institution/CITL/Business%20and%20Computer%20Technologies/CPS/261/UpdatedFiles/FromF2017/CPS261_JH1_Homework.pdf)

And I got stuck writing the part of the assignment where I need to add the ints into the output file. Here is my code right here,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JH1_00668860 {
    public static void printToScreen(String filename) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            scan = new Scanner(fis);
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("printToScreen: can't open: " + filename);
        } finally {
            if (scan != null)
                scan.close();
        }
    }// end of prin

    public static void process(String inputFilename) {
        String fileoutputname = null;
        FileInputStream file = null;
        Scanner scan = null;
        FileOutputStream outputFilename = null;
        OutputStream ps = null;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(inputFilename);
            scan = new Scanner(file);
            fileoutputname = scan.next();
            System.out.println(fileoutputname + "asfasdfasdfasdf");





            outputFilename = new FileOutputStream(fileoutputname);
            ps = new FileOutputStream(fileoutputname);
            if (scan.hasNextInt() && scan.nextInt() >= 0) {
                System.out.println(scan.nextInt() + "asfs");
                ps.write(scan.nextInt());





            } else {
                System.out.println("You have ran out of data or you have a bad value");
            }

            System.out.println("A file was created");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("You ran into an exception :" + e);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("You ran into an exception :" + e);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (file != null) {
                    file.close();

                }
                if (outputFilename != null) {
                    outputFilename.close();

                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();

                }
//              FileInputStream st = new FileInputStream(fileoutputname);
//              int contents = st.read();
//              while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
//                  System.out.print(contents);
//              }
                if (scan != null) {
                    scan.close();
                }
                printToScreen(fileoutputname);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("there was an exception");
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        process("file2.txt");

    }
}
```

When I run it the console shows [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqwOI.png)
And then I go to the file on my computer named niceJob.txt which is starting as an empty file, Eclipse then says it is going to be changed, but then when i "reload" nothing shows up.

Can anyone help me debug this bug(or if it is some other thing that is happening?) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Well one problem I see right away is that you are calling `.nextInt()` three times and only writing once to the file, so you're throwing two of those reads away.

Comment: *"Can anyone help me debug this bug"* - Have your tried using your IDE's debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your code `ps.write(scan.nextInt());` try to put `ps.write.flush();` or `ps.flush();`

EDIT:
If it still doesn't work add imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
```

and change `ps.write(scan.nextInt());` to

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(inputFilename)); 
writer.write(Integer.toString(scan.nextInt));  
writer.newLine();
writer.flush();
```

Comment: I tried flush and write but the data wont go into the file

Comment: I mean it should be both of them ps.write(scan.nextInt()); + ps.write.flush(); in next line, or ps.write(scan.nextInt()); + ps.flush();